# Issue with writing simple TCP server in python

Tags: python, html, tcp

I am writing a is simple TCP server using python. when i type in "localhost:12001/HelloWorld.html" into my web browser it is meant to display "Hello world" from the html file saved in my directory.

When i run it, this is what is displayed in my web browser:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
  <title></title>
  <meta name="Generator" content="Cocoa HTML Writer">
  <meta name="CocoaVersion" content="2113.5">
  <style type="text/css">
    p.p1 {margin: 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px 0.0px; font: 13.0px 'Helvetica Neue'; color: #000000; -webkit-text-stroke: #000000}
    span.s1 {font-kerning: none}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
<p class="p1"><span class="s1">Hello World !</span></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my source code :

```
from socket import *

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM) 
serverPort = 12001
serverSocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:

    print('Ready to serve...')
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

    try:

        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
        filename = message.split()[1]
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read()
     
# #Send one HTTP header line into socket
        connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n')
        
#Send the content of the requested file to the client
        for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
    #Send response message for file not found
        print('404 Not Found')
        connectionSocket.send("""HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n""".encode());

#Close client socket
        connectionSocket.close()
```

any help is appreciated , thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Don't send your text one character at a time in a loop**

Change this:

```py
for i in range(0, len(outputdata)):
    connectionSocket.send(outputdata[i])
```

To this:

```py
connectionSocket.send(outputdata)
```

2. **Encode all response strings as utf-8 bytes**

```py
outputdata = f.read().encode(encoding='utf-8')
```

3. **Add the Content-Length and Content-Type headers to response**

So browser will know how to use this

```py
connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: %d\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n'
                      .format(outputlength)
                      .encode(encoding='utf-8'))
```

`Content-Length` is a length of your data in bytes (outputdata)

`Content-Type` tells the browser how to interpret the response (text/html)

**My working example of your code:**

```py
from socket import *

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
serverPort = 12001
serverSocket.bind(('127.0.0.1', serverPort))
serverSocket.listen(1)

while True:
    print('Ready to serve...')
    connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()
    
    try:
        message = connectionSocket.recv(1024).decode()
        filename = message.split()[1]
        f = open(filename[1:])
        outputdata = f.read().encode(encoding='utf-8')
        outputlength = len(outputdata)
        
        # #Send one HTTP header line into socket
        connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: %d\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n'
                              .format(outputlength)
                              .encode(encoding='utf-8'))
        
        # Send the content of the requested file to the client
        connectionSocket.send(outputdata)
        connectionSocket.close()
    except IOError:
        # Send response message for file not found
        print('404 Not Found')
        connectionSocket.send("""HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found\r\n""".encode())
        
        # Close client socket
        connectionSocket.close()
```

Comment: throws this error:                                                           connectionSocket.send(f'HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Length: {outputlength}\r\nContent-Type: text/html\r\n\r\n'.encode(encoding='utf-8'))
                                                                                                                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @elsmooth, sorry, I updated code in the post to use .format() function, not a string interpolation (possibly you're using an older version of python). If everything works correctly and this answer solves your problem, then accept it, have a good day :)